# How to unlink Github from Sentry account?

Tags: github, heroku, profile, account, sentry

I'm using Sentry for my python application to catch errors. Now, I want to link my GitHub account with Sentry, to see additional information.

Some time ago, I already had a Sentry account with GitHub linked, but deleted it for some reason. Now, every time I try to link the accounts Sentry tells me that this GitHub account is already linked to another account (which was deleted). In my GitHub account settings, I already revoked all access Sentry had and tried it again, but it still doesn't work. What to do?

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have credentials cached regarding Sentry in your credential helper:

```
git config credential.helper
```

(a [Windows one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39592537/6309) or a [MacOS one](https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain) or a [Linux one](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2016/11/21/gnome-keyring-git-credential-helper/))

If you see any "Sentry" entry, delete it, and try again.

But, from the screenshot, that seems to be a server-side issue, which means [GitHub support](https://github.com/contact) can sort it out: if the old GitHub account is registered on GitHub side, then the local credential cache is *not* involved.

Comment: There are'nt any Sentry entries.

Comment: @SpinningPlays OK. Can you edit your question with the full command and error message that you see?

Comment: @SpinningPlays Can you open the Windows Credentials Manager and check for any entry referencing your old GitHub account?

Comment: Nothing there too... I told the support about my issue and I think they can solve it.

Comment: @SpinningPlays A server-side issue, then. I have edited the answer accordingly.